# Can we translate "to Königsplatz" as "nach Königsplatz" when indicating a direction?

Tags: preposition

> Welcher Bus fährt nach/zum Königsplatz?

According to a website, *nach* is used to reference places of geographical locations or directions.
So, my question is: Is *Königsplatz* not a geographical location because it wants to use "zum" as the correct answer?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: That question and answers are in German, so not a duplicate since questions should be answered in the language asked.

Comment: @RDBury: Bevor johnl die Frage editiert hat war sie auf Deutsch. Sie lautete *»Könnte nach in diesem Satz benutzen werden?«* Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/65721/revisions

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: I see your point. It appears that the body of the question was in English with the title in German, leading to confusion all around. I was basically just trying to remind people that, at least according to custom here, it's not a duplicate question if it's in a different language. I think some people hit "close" without considering such factors.

Comment: @RDBury: Da erhebt sich die Frage, als in welcher Sprache man eine Frage als gestellt ansehen soll, wenn der Titel vollständig auf Deutsch verfasst wurde und der Körper Anteile in Deutsch und Englisch enthält. Das hat auch Auswirkungen auf die Frage, ob Johnls Veränderung überhaupt zulässig war.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Like I said, "confusion all around". It seems to be common with newbies to ask questions "bilingually"; I'm not sure why. As for what to do about it, it sounds to me like a question for Meta.

Comment: Reasonable minds can differ, I suppose, but the German title was rather undescriptive and the question in the body was clearly in English, so I figured it would make sense (by the principle of least astonishment, if you will) to not only expand the title, but also tailor it to the language of the body. So that, if you don't speak English, you don't have to click on the link as you won't understand what's there. I understand you could argue that there's value in preserving the bilinguality of the question, though, but that was the idea. You may feel free to retranslate it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, the names of streets, squares, roads etc. are always definite in German, so that's how you can tell that something like *nach Königsplatz* can't be correct - this is also why it's *zum Königsplatz* (contraction of *zu dem Königsplatz*) rather than just *zu Königsplatz*.

There is no direct German equivalent to English "to". Directional prepositions in German are complex and generalisations like the one you came across are no help at all, I'm afraid. RDBury's answer covered some of this, but here's a comprehensive set of examples:

**Street names**

- Wir gehen **zum** Königsplatz. (We're travelling to Königsplatz.)
- Wir gehen **auf den** Königsplatz. (We're stepping onto Königsplatz.)
- Wir gehen **zur** Schillerstraße. (We're going to Schillerstraße.)
- Wir fahren **in die** Schillerstraße. (We're entering Schillerstraße.)

**Cities and neighbourhoods**

- Wir fahren **nach** Berlin. (We're going to Berlin.)
- Wir fahren **auf den** Prenzlauer Berg. (We're going to Prenzlauer Berg [a neighbourhood in Berlin].)
- Wir fahren **nach** Köln. (We're going to Cologne.)
- Wir fahren **zum** Eifeltor. (We're going to Eifeltor [a neighbourhood in Cologne].)

**Countries**

- Wir fahren **nach** Italien. (We're going to Italy.)
- Wir fahren **in die** Schweiz. (We're going to Switzerland.)
- Wir fliegen **auf die** Seychellen. (We're flying to the Seychelles.)

Comment: What does "are always definite" mean?

Comment: There is a remote possibility that if you consider the "Königsplatz" an abstract target instead of the concrete square "nach" is used (The tramway in Bonn, as an example, does exactly that: "Strassenbahn nach Bertha-von-Suttner-Platz")

Comment: @c.p. Google "definiteness". The expression "**the** tree"/"**der** Baum" is definite, while "tree/Baum" on its own is indefinite, as is "a tree/ein Baum".

English has _some_ definite placenames ("the Scottish Highlands", "the Gambia"), but German has loads of them, e.g. "die Schweiz" (Switzerland), and pretty much any street/road/square, so while English has "Piccadilly Square" rather than "the Piccadilly Square", German has "der Alexanderplatz" rather than just "Alexanderplatz".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't feel like googlling anything. I just don't agree that definiteness is a criterion here. You wrote (correctly) *Wir fahren nach Italien* and *Italien* is also, according to your idea, definite (there is no, excepting abstractions, *ein Italien*) but it has no article.

Comment: @tofro Indeed -- in this case it refers to the tram stop named after the square, not the square itself.

Answer (score 1):

In general, use *nach* for larger geographical locations: countries, states, cities. (There are exceptions to this though, for instance use *in* for countries which use an article.) Since you're talking about a bus, which is presumably going to drop you off somewhere near *Königsplatz* and not actually "inside", you'd probably use *zu*. If you were already nearby and were talking about actually entering *Königsplatz*, then I'm guessing you'd use *auf*. Certain open areas such as a *Platz* prefer *auf*, though some (such as a *Park*) prefer *in*.